# No sound from Headphone Jack on an Asus G46vw

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Suddenly my headphone jack has stopped working. I believe it happened after an update. It worked for a long time previously. I've searched everywhere looking for known issues before posting this, and I've used the Alsamixer thing with the 00 or MM for mute/on. I've messed with my sound settings. Uninstalled and reinstalled. Edited some "Element Speaker" ignore/on setting in a config file. Nothing's working.

I'm using UBuntu 14.04. My computer is an Asus G46VW  660m with Intel i5 3230m
The only thing I can add is when muting/unmuting from the Alsamixer/terminal program the fuzz would pop when i'd turn on/off. So to me it indicates the jack has power to it. But, I cannot get sound to channel to it.

Comment: I know there is an issue with Pulseaudio with this. The headphone jack doesn't work on my computer either, so it isn't a problem with your laptop specifically.